# Is there a proper way to transform a 2D array in a reference 1D

Tags: arrays, rust, unsafe

I tried to transform a 2D array to a ref in rust like contigueous 2D array in c/c++ but the only way i found to do it is a little bit sucpicious ... this is how I do it:

```
let mut a=[[0u8;10];10];
let a_ref= unsafe {
    slice::from_raw_parts_mut(a.as_mut_ptr().addr()as *mut u8,100)
};
a_ref.iter().for_each(|i|print!("{i} "))
```

the equivalent in c might be:

```
int main() {
    int a[3][3]={
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9},
    };
    int *pA=a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        printf("%d ",pA[i]);
}
```

Is there a proper way to do it in rust ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For casting raw pointers, we use [`cast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.cast) and not `addr() as _`, but other than that your code is fine:

```rust
let mut a = [[0u8; 10]; 10];
let a_ref = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts_mut(a.as_mut_ptr().cast::<u8>(), 100) };
a_ref.iter().for_each(|i| print!("{i} "));
```

You can do it simpler by casting a pointer directly, no need to construct a slice:

```rust
let a_ref = unsafe { &mut *(&mut a as *mut [[u8; 10]; 10] as *mut [u8; 100]) };
```

On nightly Rust, you can also use [`flatten_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.flatten_mut), but that gives you a slice and not an array:

```rust
#![feature(slice_flatten)]

let a = [[0u8; 10]; 10];
let a_ref: &[u8] = a.flatten_mut();
a_ref.iter().for_each(|i| print!("{i} "));
```

For flattening slices, there are multiple crates out there and as I said it was also introduced into the standard library; flattening arrays was not implemented for the simple reason that it's impossible to implement generically without `generic_const_exprs`.

Comment: If I had to chose betwen them should i use a certain way to do in function of the utilization or there is a best

Comment: @Joshua The best way is of course without any unsafe code, using the standard library (but this requires nightly); between the other two ways, I have a slight preference for the array-only way.